# Php order elements array by one part of value

Tags: php, sorting

If i have for example this array with this values :

```
<?php

$aa=array(

"3456-898rterew",
"22-sdfsdf78",
"214-5548sdfsdf",

);

?>
```

How i can order elements by number until of "-" , by other side i need specificate the second number and show numbers from more high to more low and beside put the second number after "-"

**I try this :**

```
<?php


for ($i=0;$i<count($aa);$i++)
{

$arr[]="".$aa[$i]."";

}


arsort($arr);


foreach($arr as $ar)
{
print "".$ar." <br>";
}


?>
```

In this case i get the order bad , and i can´t get the result i want in this order :

```
3456-898rterew
214-5548sdfsdf
22-sdfsdf78
```

The until order it´s right and need show this in this way

From more high number to more lower if no insert the second number after "-" i get but the numbers created are creatred in this way.

Comment: Did you try the [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function (and explode function or regex to extract the first part of your number) ?

Comment: FYI, you have an extra comma in your array definition.

Comment: @EdCottrell: Doesn't matter in PHP.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't make it good practice or clean code.

Comment: You don't need to do `"".$aa[$i].""`, just do `$aa[$i]`.

Comment: @EdCottrell: From that page: `For multi-line arrays on the other hand the trailing comma is commonly used, as it allows easier addition of new elements at the end.`

Comment: @EdCottrell Actually, the extra comma is recommended in the case of [Associative arrays](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.arrays.associative)

Comment: "commonly used" =/= "good" Just sayin'.

Comment: Thank´s for yours comments but how i can fix my code please , thank´s everybody

Comment: @user3093290: Does the [existing solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20620897/1438393) not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this task PHP http://php.net/usort is the correct method. you can define a custom function to sort an array if any standard array sort method does not fit with your task.

like this

```
$aa=array(
    "3456-898rterew",
    "22-sdfsdf78",
    "214-5548sdfsdf"
);

usort($aa, function($a, $b){

    // separate string 
    $a = explode('-', $a, 2);
    $b = explode('-', $b, 2);

    // select first part before -
    $a = $a[0];
    $b = $b[0];

    // check if values are equal then do nothing
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }

    // if $a bigger then $b - push array $a index lower then $b 
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_R($aa);
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => 3456-898rterew [1] => 214-5548sdfsdf [2] => 22-sdfsdf78 )
```

Comment: Note: array access on functions returns like `explode('-', $a, 2)[0]` will not work in PHP < 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Use [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) with a callback. Use `array_map()` with `explode()` to create an array containing the numbers. Then, use `array_combine()` to create a new array with the values of the original array as keys and the number-array as values:

Code:

```
usort($aa, function ($a, $b) use ($aa) {
    $arr = array_combine(
        array_values($aa), array_map(function($item) { 
            return explode('-', $item)[0]; 
        }, $aa)
    );
    return $arr[$a] < $arr[$b];
});

print_r($aa);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3456-898rterew
    [1] => 214-5548sdfsdf
    [2] => 22-sdfsdf78
)
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP allows you to supply your own comparison function for the sort function [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort), this is what you want to use to sort data if the standard sort functions aren't suitable.

First, your comparison function:

```
// printf calls are for illustration
function my_compare($a, $b) {
  printf("comparing %s to %s:  ", $a, $b);

  // split
  $a_parts = explode('-', $a);
  $b_parts  =explode('-', $b);

  //cast
  $a_int = intval($a_parts[0]);
  $b_int = intval($b_parts[0]);

  // compare
  if( $a_int < $b_int ) {
    printf("%s < %s \n", $a, $b);
    return 1;
  } else if( $a_int == $b_int ) {
    printf("%s == %s \n", $a, $b);
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("%s > %s \n", $a, $b);
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Then it's simply `usort($aa, 'my_compare');`.

Output:

```
comparing 22-sdfsdf78 to 3456-898rterew:  22-sdfsdf78 < 3456-898rterew
comparing 214-5548sdfsdf to 22-sdfsdf78:  214-5548sdfsdf > 22-sdfsdf78
comparing 3456-898rterew to 214-5548sdfsdf:  3456-898rterew > 214-5548sdfsdf
array (
  0 => '3456-898rterew',
  1 => '214-5548sdfsdf',
  2 => '22-sdfsdf78',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP >= 5.3:

```
usort($aa, function ($a, $b) {
    $a = array_shift(explode('-', $a));
    $b = array_shift(explode('-', $b));
    return ($a < $b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In an object orientated way PHP brings the SplHeap object with the native Standard Php Library (SPL). So you can build a simple Iterator to solve your problem.

```
class YourSplHeap extends SplHeap {

    public function compare( $value1, $value2 ) {
        $number1 = explode("-", $value1);
        $number2 = explode("-", $value2);

        return ($number1[0] - $number2[0]);
    }
}

$heap = new YourSplHeap();
$heap->insert("3456-898rterew");
$heap->insert("22-sdfsdf78");
$heap->insert("214-5548sdfsdf");

foreach ($heap as $entry) {
    echo $entry . "<br />";
}
```

The obove shown class is a variation of the SplMaxHeap object of the SPL. It compares all inserts, splits them by "-", compares the integer values and sorts them keeping the maximum at the top. So the expected result looks like this:

```
3456-898rterew
214-5548sdfsdf
22-sdfsdf78
```